# Unable to retrieve data on a removable device using a Windows service in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, service

I am trying to detect the insertion of removable devices and retrieve the drive letter of said device using an NT service. I have been successful in detecting insertion and removal of devices, but have been unable to setup a `DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME` structure which would allow me to get the drive letter, GUID etc... from the volume.

```
case SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT:{
            switch(evtype){
            case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:{
                    DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME *hdr = (DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME*) evdata;
                    ofstream log ("C:\\log.txt", ios::app);
                    log << hdr->dbcv_devicetype;
                    log.close();
                }
                break;
```

The above code snippet compiles and runs correctly, but when I insert a flash drive,`hdr->dbcv_devicetype` logs as a value of `55555` and `DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME` (which is what a USB drive is) is defined as `2` (`hdr->dbcv_devicetype` should equal `DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME` because I inserted a flash drive). For some reason either the `DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME` is not initializing correctly, or something else I am doing is wrong. I am using Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2011 C++.

Comment: Have you considered that drives and drivers lie?
the difference between a "external USB hard drive" and an "internal USB hard drive" is arbitrary. Not to mention that technically the definition of "disk" and "volume" and Drive  are difference...
Oh and for bonus points what LOCAL_SYSTEM sees a C:\ doesn't have to be what the user sees as c:\

Comment: Ideally you should do this in the context of the user as drive letter mappings are managed on a per-user basis.  If you are able to do that then you can greatly simplify your task as explorer already does the hard work; you can use a simple call to SHChangeNotifyRegister() to get the notifications.

Comment: @Luke That idea sounds good, but will it still detect drives that are not mounted? For example Windows won't mount a Linux file system, it will just inform the user to format it. Would `SHChangeNotifyRegister()` pick the insertion up even though it's not being mounted to a drive letter like `E:\\`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR lpdb = (PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR)evdata;
  if (lpdb -> dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
   {
    PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME lpdbv = (PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)lpdb;

    if (lpdbv -> dbcv_flags & DBTF_MEDIA)
     {
      StringCchPrintf( szMsg, sizeof(szMsg)/sizeof(szMsg[0]), 
                       TEXT("Drive %c: Media has arrived.\n"), 
                       FirstDriveFromMask(lpdbv ->dbcv_unitmask) );

      MessageBox( hwnd, szMsg, TEXT("WM_DEVICECHANGE"), MB_OK );
     }
   }

   /*------------------------------------------------------------------
      FirstDriveFromMask( unitmask )

      Description
        Finds the first valid drive letter from a mask of drive letters.
        The mask must be in the format bit 0 = A, bit 1 = B, bit 2 = C, 
        and so on. A valid drive letter is defined when the 
        corresponding bit is set to 1.

      Returns the first drive letter that was found.
   --------------------------------------------------------------------*/

   char FirstDriveFromMask( ULONG unitmask )
    {
     char i;

     for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
      {
       if (unitmask & 0x1)
         break;
       unitmask = unitmask >> 1;
      }

     return( i + 'A' );
   }
```

Code pulled from [Detecting Media Insertion or Removal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The code to detect removal of device is included in the link.

Comment: I had to modify your code a bit as it was throwing some errors that crashed the service. I posted the changes [here.](http://pastebin.com/3Fyb3b1p) Problem is every time I insert a drive, it says the drive letter is 'A' (without quotes). I tried many devices too. Not sure why this is happening, perhaps it is the `FirstDriveFromMask()` function? I tried using that code in a win32 console app and it manged to work perfectly so I'm thoroughly confused here. It must be something specific to Windows Services.

Comment: Well they used the top Window message loop to get their message; however I don't think it would be that hard to adapt.
Concerning the issue with only the drive letter 'A' showing up, try to remove the break statement, and see how many bits were set.
It could be that on your computer the drive A bit is always set and this algorithm stops at the first drive letter.

Comment: I took your suggestion and commented out `break;` and ran it though a debugger. `unitmask` appears to have the value of `0x53f56307` when a drive is inserted. I tested this with 2 separate drives, leaving one inserted and inserting another to ensure different drive letter assignment. Both have the value of `0x53f56307`.